# SPARK Task not serializable due to assert statement

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization

I am getting "Task not serializable" error due to assert statement in foreach method on an RDD. Is there any work around to write assert for every element of RDD ?

```
class myTest extends Funsuite {

  //some code to create spark context(sc)

  var arrRDD = sc.parallelize(Array(1,1,1,1,1))

  test("custom test"){
     arrRDD.foreach{
        x => {
           //commenting out this assert removes the error
           assert(x == 1)
        } 
     }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RDD (Resilient Distributed Dataset)** is a collection which is distributed over a nodes in a cluster, When we work, we just see as a collection in single machine which is due to abstraction.

When you run `RDD.map` or any other transformation like `map`, `filter` etc this is serialized and moved to other nodes on cluster and executes on these nodes.

The error in your`"Task not serializable"` is due to the transformation `arrRDD.foreach` which is serialized but the method inside it `"assert"` is not serialized, So it cannot be moved to the other nodes.

If you care trying to `assert` the values you can just `collect` it, which brings the data to driver node as an `array` an `assert` it as

```
arrRDD.collect().foreach{
  x => assert (x == 1)
}
```

But I don't think it is still a good way!

Hope this helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test this small usecase, you can collect it into an actual scala collection and then use the assert on that. Just like Shankar said.

If you want a broader scope of unit tests you can use a [unit testing framework](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/wiki/RDDComparisons).